# Remove duplicate entry but keep relationship

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name | Product | Total
----  --------- ------
A       Toy       $5
A       Car       $30,000
A       Equipment $500
B       Car       $100,000
```

etc...

I would like to remove the duplicate name entries but keep the relationship to the product example:

```
Name | Product | Total
----  --------- ------
A       Toy       $5
        Car       $30,000
        Equipment $500
B       Car       $100,000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed you want to make `Name = ''` because you cannot delete the duplicate records.

So you can use a [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) function inside a [`WITH`](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php) clause and update `Name` field

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) AS Rn
            ,Name
            ,Product
            ,Total
    FROM yourTable
)
UPDATE C
SET Name = ''
WHERE Rn <> 1
```

Comment: worked, thanks! For anyone that is looking for a solution at a presentation level you can also use BREAK ON [column or alias name]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `Name` only when `Product ='Toy'` then use `Case` statement

```
Select case when Product ='Toy' then Name else '' END as Name,
       Product,
       Total
From yourtable
```

Comment: It just so happens that the first item in Product is toy, it can be any product, apologies should have stated that

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY i.name),
i.name,i.product,i.Total
FROM yourtable i
)
SELECT
case when prev.name = cte.name
then
' '
else
cte.name
end as name,
cte.address,
cte.Total
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
```